# How to increase logical volume of a disk in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

`df -h` command returns

```
[root@ip-SERVER_IP ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  5.5G  2.0G  74% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
cm_processes     32G     0   32G   0% /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process
```

I have a volume with 500GB of disk space.

Now, I installed some stuff in `/dev/xvda1` and it keeps saying that:

```
The Cloudera Manager Agent's parcel directory is on a filesystem with less than 5.0 GiB of its space free. /opt/cloudera/parcels (free: 1.9 GiB (25.06%), capacity: 7.7 GiB)
```

Similarly:

```
The Cloudera Manager Agent's log directory is on a filesystem with less than 2.0 GiB of its space free. /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent (free: 1.9 GiB (25.06%), capacity: 7.7 GiB)
```

From the memory stats, I see that the Filesystem above stuff is installed in must be:

```
/dev/xvda1
```

I believe it needs to be resized so as to have more disk space but I don't think I need to expand the volume. I have only installed some stuff and started with it.

So I would like to know what exact steps I need to follow to expand the space in this partition and where exactly is my 500 GB?

I would like to know it step by step since I cannot afford to lose what I have on the server already. Please help

```
lsblk:
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
xvda 202:0 0 500G 0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1 0 8G 0 part /
```

Comment: It seems an advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. This question should be asked under serverfault.com.
2. Don't "expand" the volume. It is not common practice to expand root drive in Linux for none-OS folder. Since your stuff is inside `/opt/cloudera/parcels` ,  what you need to do is allocate a new partition, mount it, then copy  for it.  example is shown here : [paritioning & moving](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving). (assume /home is your /top/cloudera/parcels".
3. To check your disk volume , try this   `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`

(update)
In fact, if you create your EC2 instance under EBS volume, you don't need to allocate 500GB upfront. You can allocate smaller space, then expand the disk space following this step : [Expanding the Storage Space of an EBS Volume on Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html).   You should create a snapshot for the EBS before perform those task.  However, there is a catch of EBS disk IOPS, if you allocate less space, there will be less IOPS given. So if you allocate 500GB , you will get 500x 3 = max 1500 IOPS.

Comment: Thanks. But the major confusion here is I am not able to undertstand why create a new partition? Creating a new partition means I buy more hard disk /volume right? In this case, where is the 500Gib I already got while creating the instance? Why would the root partition itself shall have so small percentage of the total hard disk I get?

Comment: @gags : did you run `sudo lsblk` to see where all the disk space allocated?  If you didn't allocate them, they will remains idle.  And bare in mind that, if you use SSD Instance Store Volumes, you can't expand the given space as offer by EBS.

Comment: This is what I get from lsblk:NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  500G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /

Comment: While creating the instance , I asked for 500Gib and added this host. Now, these partitions were created automatically which I have referred to in my question and since cloudera parcels got installed in xvda1, it is complaining about lack of disk space. My confusion is why should be that if I did not ask for partitions as they were created and now that leads to me create a new instance with 500Gib in root which I suppose is what I did while creating this first instance as well

Comment: so, xvda seems to have 500Gib and xvda1 8G. How come?

Comment: @gags : Because in AWS, if you use all default value for EC2, OS `/` is set to 8GB.  The remaining you must format and mount it yourself.  Go experiment with the EC2 launching wizard (just don't do the last step), you will know what I mean.

Comment: Thanks. I did try that. I see that while creating the instance through launch wizard: It says: Root /dev/sda1 8Gib where I modified 8 Gib to 500Gib and went on. How do I mount and remount the partitions and if I go about that, does it mean that xvda1 (wherein my cloudera parcels seem to be installed would automatically have the volume extended or do I need to do something else? I was adviced to create an AMI of the system and assign 500Gib to root which I did earlier as well and was no different

Comment: If you modify the value as say, your `/dev/xvda1` will be given 500GB.  Now what you can do is create a `/dev/xvda2` from the remaining disk space, mount it on top of `/opt/cloudera/parcels`.  OTH, about your AMI question, it is a BAD idea.  Please split all your question and post it on `serverfault.com`.

Answer (score 0):

This [AWS LVM](https://devopsideas.com/working-logical-volume-manager-lvm/) link gives you a step by step instruction on how to increase the size of Logical Volume in AWS EC2

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)